# How to create installer exe in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installshield, advanced-installer

I use Advance Installer for Visual Studio to create executable file from my project.

My problem is that: When I create an .exe file, it works on my PC, but when I install on another PC, it does not work (it does not open even).

Can you help me if you have already had a case like such bug please?

Comment: Please work to improve this question. Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: You are using the freeware version of Advance Installer?
You rebuild your project in Visual Studio with Release mode?
Did you try to copy your application from your /bin/Release folder to another PC (possible for simple apps only)?

Comment: i use Advanced Installer 12.8. and i see this tutorial to create my .exe file.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0v6hmumCFU

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that you didn't include your EXE app dependencies into your installer project too. In Visual Studio just open your Advanced Installer setup project, select its "Files and Folders" section and use the "Add Project Output" button to add the project references into your installer too.

Hopefully this will help you.